# Recursive Dynamic Angular Form; EmitEvent from Deeper Child to Root (Parent Component)

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-event-emitter, recursive-component

Hi I'm newbie and I'm creating a project with a `Reactive Form`; based on `Recursive` Component that creates `Dynamic Form` from `JSON` file. The Sources

##### This is an adaptation from Ionic based on [Creating Dynamic Angular Forms with JSON](https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/creating-dynamic-angular-forms-with-json/)

I Adapted the Recursive version procedures and other changes!
My code is located in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fjson-form%2Fjson-form.component.html).

My component `SelectsComponent` located in the ***selects.component.ts*** file, has the selector `selector: 'selects',` I have:

```
  @Output() addControl = new EventEmitter<JsonFormControls>();
```

and the method

```
  public onSelectChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    console.log('parent:' + this.parentControl || 'root');
    this.control.value = event + '';
    if (this.control.children) {
      this.recursiveConcealer(this.control.children);
      const child = this.control.children.find(
        (child) => child.value === event + ''
      );
      this.newControl(child);
      if (child.siblings) {
        for (let sibling of child.siblings) {
          this.newControl(sibling);
        }
      }
      //Emit Event to Root
      this.addControl.emit(child);
    }
  }
```

When the `onSelectChange` method is called, then emit is performed `this.addControl.emit(child);`

In the `template` ***selects.component.html*** file, I have this code:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of control?.children">
    <div fxFlex="100%">
      <selects
        *ngIf="child.type === 'select'"
        [control]="child"
        [parentControl]="control"
        [formBuilder]="formBuilder"
      ></selects>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

I have the `JsonFormComponent` located in the ***json-form.component.ts*** file, with this method:

```
  public onAddControl(addControlEvent: JsonFormControls) {
    this.addControl(addControlEvent);
    addControlEvent.visible = true;
  }
```

In it's `template` ***json-form.component.html*** file, with this code:

```
<selects
  *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
  [control]="control"
  [visible]="true"
  (addControl)="onAddControl($event)"
  [formBuilder]="myFormBuilder"
></selects>
```

The problem raise when some Child-component (`SelectsComponent`) is not a direct son of the Root Parent-Component (`JsonFormComponent`), maybe is a grandson or depeer relation, as:

(level 0)`JsonFormComponent` -> (level 1)`SelectsComponent` -> (level 2)`SelectsComponent` -> (level 3)`SelectsComponent`

How re-emit from `SelectsComponent` child to `SelectsComponent`parent.

QUESTIONS:

1. **How to send or Emit Event from (level 3)`SelectsComponent` to (level 0)`JsonFormComponent` ?**
2. **How to send some Event of Acknowledgment from (level 0)`JsonFormComponent` to (level 3)`SelectsComponent`?**

Thanks in advance!

***I appreciate answer not based on `services` that I know could be an alternative.***

EDIT:

[image]

What is the `Console.log(...)` expected?

```
console.log(`parent: ${this.parentControl?this.parentControl.name:'root'} -> control.name: ${this.control.name} -> Emitter: ${e?.name}` );
```

The first(or root)  component is `company`

Something like:

```
parent: root -> control.name: company -> {Here the last node child}.
```

According to the click in the previous image

1st click (first level):

```
parent: root -> control.name: company -> Emitter: Petitioner (C2 -> P2).
```

2nd click (second level):

```
parent: root -> control.name: company -> Emitter: Service (C2 -> P2 -> S2).
```

Example: 3nd click (third level):

```
parent: root -> control.name: company -> Emitter: Request (C2 -> P2 -> S2 -> R2).
```

The console.log (or future operations) only will be performed in the context of the root (that is `company`).

Comment: @check this post https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3513-playing-with-recursive-components-in-angular-6-1-10.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated solution in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6kccps

1.How to send or Emit Event from (level 3)SelectsComponent to (level 0)JsonFormComponent ?

Listen to the addControl event emitted by child `selects` component  in the selects.component.html

```
  <selects
    *ngIf="child.type === 'select'"
    [control]="child"
    [parentControl]="control"
    [formBuilder]="formBuilder"
    (addControl)="handleAddControl($event)"
  ></selects>
```

Emit the event

```
handleAddControl(data: any) {
    this.addControl.emit(data);
  }
```

This will send events from every instance of `SelectsComponent` to be bubbled up to the top JsonFormComponent

2.How to send some Event of Acknowledgment from (level 0)JsonFormComponent to (level 3)SelectsComponent?

I am not really sure what is needed in terms of sending an acknowledge. However, I assume upon receiving an acknowledge in the original instance you would be performing some action, like updating some property. It can be achieved by adding a callback to the event payload as follows:
selects.component.ts

```
 //Emit Event to Root
public onSelectChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
...
...
...
 const data = {child,
  callback: () => {
    console.log('Executing callback for control with label', this.control.name)
  }
}   

this.addControl.emit(data);
```

Execute the callback in json-form.component.ts

```
  public onAddControl(addControlEvent: any) {
    if (addControlEvent.callback) {
      addControlEvent.callback();
    }
    this.addControl(addControlEvent);
    addControlEvent.visible = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are answers to your questions(I hope);

1. You can inject SelectsComponent into himself:

   @Optional() @SkipSelf() private selectsComponent: SelectsComponent

and then subscribe on self addControl EE and push his value to injected instance:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.selectsComponent) {
      this.addControl
        .subscribe(e => {
          this.selectsComponent.addControl.next(e);
        });
    }

    this.form = this.rootFormGroup.form;
  }
```

In this case, you are synchronizing all nested EEs;

2. For your second question I think the solution is to pass data/subject into the Input decorator of each SelectComponent(bind to children selects Input data which you get into host component).

I have prepared an example of how your first question works, check SelectsComponent. As see each child component triggers his parent addControl: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkvmrr)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer unfortunately I get: `ERROR
Error: _this._throwIfClosed is not a function`

Comment: @joseluisbz sorry, stackblitz didn't save my last changes, now it works, check my link again, please

Comment: Is it possible when Only the parent receive the event print a message wtih the name of child Sender?; I'm trying to looks for but I lost :( Thanks in advance

Comment: @joseluisbz check stackblitz, I rewrite subscription and type of addControl EE, now control when the emitting event it sends a name of the control. But you need to handle add control interface.
this.selectsComponent.addControl.next(
          e?.name ? e : { name: this.control.name, e }
        );

Comment: I don't want to be annoying, because you are the only one who has invested time. I made a Edit in order to be more explicit.

Comment: @joseluisbz I think for your case the best solution is a service. When your components must communicate through a few levels then services are will be cleaner solutions than some chains of subscriptions